# vscode the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding

Tags: visual-studio-code, binaryfiles

I am trying to work by importing the photo2cartoon project from github into my vscode.
https://github.com/kairess/photo2cartoon

But some files are not read in vscode.(model_mobilefacenet,photo2cartoon_weights.pt)
When I try to open it I get the message (the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding)
if i click (open anyway)
[image]

and my vscode terminal say
[image]

but the files are in the same directory
[image]

how to fix this problem